# Finding Big Theta of Recurrence Relation $8T(n/3)+n^2/\log_3(n)$

Tags: summation, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, geometric-series

Getting stuck on finding the geometric series after finding the sum for this recurrence. I didn't think master theorem applied to this because I thought n^2/log3(n) was not a polynomial but I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))?

Comment: yes, but I thought it did not work for this recurrence. am I mistaken?

Comment: Perhaps wolfram can help with the series expansion: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8T%28n%2F3%29%2Bn%5E2%2Flog3%28n%29

Comment: A recurrence is more like $T(n)+8T(n/3)=n^2/\log_3(n)$ Is it OK?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

The master theorem *is* applicable here. In particular:

We see
$c_{\text{crit}} = \log_3(8) \approx 1.89$,
so we want to compare the term $n^2 / \log_3(n)$ with $n^{1.89}$ (roughly).

Of course, $n^2 / \log_3(n) = \Omega(n^{1.89})$ since

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 / \log_3(n)}{n^{1.89}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{.11}}{\log_3(n)} = \infty > 0
$$

So we fall into case $3$ of the master theorem (at least as listed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))).

Our last check is to show the "regularity condition" holds. That is,

$$8f(n/3) \leq k f(n)$$

for some $0 < k < 1$ and $n$ large.

Thankfully, we expand this to

$$
8 \frac{(n/3)^2}{\log_3(n/3)} \leq k \frac{n^2}{\log_3(n)}
$$

Which happens if and only if

$$
\frac{8}{9} \frac{\log_3(n)}{\log_3(n) - 1} \leq k
$$

But since $\frac{\log_3(n)}{\log_3(n) - 1}$ limits to $1$, if we choose
$8/9 < k < 1$, the desired inequality will hold for large $n$.

This lets us conclude

$$T(n) = \Theta(n^2/\log(n))$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^